# Prove that $1-\Phi(x)\leq \frac{1}{2}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}$

Tags: probability, integration, normal-distribution

I've managed to simplify it as
$\int_x^{\infty}exp(-u^2/2)[\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}-u]du\leq 0$

But I'm not sure how to prove it for all $x$ since I can only see this as obviously true when $\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\leq u$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This classical relation is only valid for $x \ge 0$.

By definition,

$$1 - \Phi(x)  = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \int_x^{+\infty} \exp{\{-u^2/2\}} du $$

By letting $v = u - x$, we get

$$ \int_x^{+\infty} \exp{\{-u^2/2\}} du = \exp{\{-x^2/2\}} \int_0^{+\infty}\exp{\{-v^2/2\}} \exp{\{-xv\}} dv $$

Then, we use that, for $x \ge 0$ and $v \ge 0$,

$$ \exp{\{-xv\}} \le 1$$

and that

$$ \int_0^{+\infty}\exp{\{-v^2/2\}}\, dv = \frac{\sqrt{2 \pi}}{2}$$

To get the desired result.

$$ 1-\Phi(x)\leq \frac{1}{2} \exp{\left(-\frac{x^2}{2}\right)} $$

Answer (score 2):

The statement only holds for $a\geq0$.

Let $\phi(a)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-a^2/2}$ the density of the standard normal distribution, and $F(a)=\int^a_{-\infty}\phi(s)\,ds$.

Let $$G(a)=1-F(a)-\frac{c}{2}\phi(a)$$
where $c=\sqrt{2\pi}$. Then
$$G'(a)=-\phi(a)+\frac{c}{2}a\phi(a)=\phi(a)(\frac{c}{2}a-1)$$
The only critical point is $a_*=\frac{2}{c}$ which corresponds to a local minimum at which $G(a_*)\approx -0.151\ldots<0$.

Notice that  $\lim_{a\rightarrow\infty}G(a)=0$ and $\lim_{a\rightarrow-\infty}G(a)=1$.
Thus, for $a$ negative but large the statement in the OP fails. For $a>0$
$$ G''(a)=-a\phi(a)(\frac{c}{2}a-1)+\phi(a)\frac{c}{2}=\phi(a)\Big(\frac{c}{2}+a-\frac{c}{2}a^2\Big)$$
and so, $G$ has only one nonnegative inflection point at $a_i=\frac{1+\sqrt{1+2c^2}}{c}$. Hence, $g(a_*)\leq G(a)<0$ for all $a>0$.